# Create a Hyperlink that searches worksheet and selects cell with duplicate contents

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a value in a cell. This value is duplicated, intentionally, in another part of the worksheet. I would like to be able to click the cell in C5 with contents 12345 and it selects the cell in A1:1600 that contains the same value. I will never have more than 2 cells with this same value in the worksheet, but the values will change.

I appreciate any help you can offer.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you ok with using VBA? - This could be done with the `Find` function...

Comment: I prefer a formula if possible, but if not, VBA is fine. The only issue I have with using VBA is this spreadsheet will be shopped around between a dozen or so facilities, having to walk each operator through how to enable macros by default is a hassle, for some of them anyway.

Comment: I think you HAVE to do this via VBA - Posting solution now...

Comment: On second thought, you could do this via the hyperlink formula, but that would mean that the cell had more than just the value in it...

Comment: That is fine. The cell already uses a rather complicated formula to return information from another worksheet. Adding another argument shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick - I was unsure of the range you wanted to specify, so I just put it as `A1:Z1600`, but change it as necessary.

In VBA, paste this into your sheet's code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

Dim OriginalAddress As String
Dim ValToFind As String
Dim CurrentCell As Range

    OriginalAddress = Target.Parent.Address
    ValToFind = Target.Parent.Value

    With Range("A1:Z1600")
        Set CurrentCell = .Find(What:=ValToFind)

        If OriginalAddress = CurrentCell.Address Then
            .FindNext(After:=CurrentCell).Activate
        Else
            CurrentCell.Activate
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Hyperlink`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/hyperlink-function-HP010062412.aspx) function to do what you wanting. But you would have to manually type out the formula for each cell that you wanted to link... Here's an example:

```
=HYPERLINK("[Book1]Sheet1!F2",12345)
```

This method is very unwieldy. The only way to do what you want in a robust fashion would be to use VBA.

---

**Edit:**  *I was able to duplicate the issue. The below edits seem to resolve the issue.*

This VBA solution used the [`FindNext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143(v=office.15).aspx) function to find the next value in the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim x As Long
x = Me.UsedRange.Rows.Count

FirstAddress = Target.Address

Set Rng = Me.UsedRange.Find(Target.Value)

If FirstAddress = Rng.Address Then
    Me.UsedRange.FindNext(Rng).Select
Else
    Rng.Select
End If

End Sub
```

This works with a double click for the sheet the code is in, and it doesn't matter where the duplicate value is in that sheet. Just place the code in your worksheet's module.

---

One last way to do this (although still inferior to VBA) is to insert the hyperlink:

[image]

In this example, you click on `A2`>go to Insert Tab>Hyperlink>Place in This Document and enter the corresponding cell. This hyperlinks cell `A2` to `F2` so that when `A2` is selected `F2` is selected.

Comment: Your VBA solution seems to select random cells. Sometimes it will go 3 or 4 cells to the right, sometimes up one. Never to the value I would expect. It is quite possibly operator error.